# Using the php substr on the_permalink() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

My urls for posts in WordPress looks like this:
http://localhost:8888/blabla/book/yes-vi-testar

Using `the_permalink()` would generate "http://localhost:8888/blabla/book/yes-vi-testar" but I want to cut the first 34 characters to get a string like "yes-vi-testar". How do I use php substr in a case like this? I'm confused... I tried

```
<?php
    $friendlypermalink = substr(the_permalink(), 34);
?>
```

but that doesnt do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get_the_permalink` to get the permalink without echoing it

So

```
substr(get_the_permalink(), .............);
```

A lot of of the Wordpress function have 'return' alternates using `get` as the operative word. IE: `get_the_time`, `get_the_content`, etc.

`the_title` is the only one I believe that doesn't have this option. For `the_title` you have to pass two empty parameters (the before and after seperators) and either a true or false ... not sure at the moment

```
the_title("","",true);
```

Answer (score -3):

As Chacha says, use get_the_permalink(). You can then do something like:

```
$url = get_the_permalink();
$text = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);

//or

preg_match('~[^/]+$~', get_the_permalink(), $m);
$text = $m[0];
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return "yes-vi-testar" ?

Comment: @bisko: yes, isn't that what the question is asking how to get though?

Comment: but this is just an attempt to reinvent basename()... and this is not the answer which told about get_permalink()...

Comment: @Tom Haigh, sorry, lost my mind for a sec there :) Didn't read the whole question.